# How to properly handle joinByArrayReverse with multiple types?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have the piece type `project` which has an `_author`, which can be of two different types:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'project',
  label: 'Project',
  pluralLabel: 'Projects',
  addFields: [
    {
      label: 'Creator',
      help: 'Person or collective who created the project.',
      name: '_author',
      idsField: 'creatorIds',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: [
        'person',
        'organization'
      ],
      filters: {
        projection: {
          _url: 1,
          title: 1,
        }
      },
      required: true
    },
    ...
```

This works perfectly fine.

On the other hand, I wish to create a reverse relationship for the authors so there can be a way to obtain their projects.

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'person',
  label: 'Person',
  pluralLabel: 'People',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_projects',
      reverseOf: '_author',
      idsField: 'creatorIds',
      type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
      withType: 'project',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          _url: 1,
          title: 1,
        }
      },
    },
    ...
```

This compiles fine, however as soon at the site loads, this error is thrown:

```
Error: I think you forgot to set idField or idsField, or you set the wrong one (use idField for byOne, idsField for byArray)
```

What is the appropriate strategy to handle this case then?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Apostrophe? I don't see this error message in the current code. One thing that jumps out is that I don't think you need `idsField` on the `joinByArrayReverse` field. That field is only used in client side code and the reverse join has no UI.

Comment: Yes, the [project is depending on v.2.108.0](https://github.com/jansensan/arts-et-medias/blob/master/package.json#L15). This error is thrown by [joinr](https://github.com/punkave/joinr), it could be coming from line 331 or 341.

Comment: I created [a simple project to test this](https://github.com/abea/minimal-apos/tree/joinReverse). I didn't experience the error after populating a few people, orgs, and jawns (it's a Philly thing). What might I be missing? Can you share a minimal test case? I do see in the docs that the `joinByArray` options have a note on polymorphic joins that "They currently do not support pieces filters or joinByArrayReverse."

Comment: So I tried to reproduce this issue in a [bare repo](https://github.com/jansensan/apos-reverse-relations), and I am unable to reproduce it either. Since then, I have added other reverse relations to my project, and they worked. This one [still doesnt work](https://github.com/jansensan/arts-et-medias/blob/master/lib/modules/aem-persons/index.js#L38) however, and I can't figure it out at all.

Comment: I am at the point where I am hacking with `apostrophe-docs:beforeSave` to be able to add the needed property to the content piece: https://github.com/jansensan/arts-et-medias/blob/develop/lib/modules/aem-persons/index.js#L260. This is still not working, because it only affects the draft mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late to contributing, but this just happened to me. The issue can be reproduced by first having the piece type be joinbyOne, creating a few pieces, and then switching the join to joinByArray.

When I did that, I had the error you highlighted. I fixed it by removing the `reverseOf` field

In your case:

```
  name: '_projects',
  idsField: 'creatorIds',
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  withType: 'project',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1,
      title: 1,
    }
  },
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/joinbyarrayreverse.html#example) it states that the field is optional as long as there's only one join with the piece type. If you have more than one join with the `person` piece type, this solution may not work. I'm still unsure why removing it solved the issue, but it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, but now every place where there was a reference to this property disappeared visually from the templates. I won't be looking at a way that brings an additional set of problems. I do appreciate you sharing the info  I will probably look at the "on before save" logic to force-save properties in the db instead.

Comment: No worries, I should've added that in as a disclaimer. We had to add back all references but at our size it was manageable.

Comment: So this was indeed a proper solution, however in order to apply it, I had to delete all the pieces from the database and re-enter them manually once the fix was applied. Not fun, but it worked.